# CGPoint and CGRect in shared framework

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, core-graphics

I am writing a framework that I would like to use in both **iOS** and **MacOS** projects.  Part of of this framework uses `CGPoint` and `CGRect` and whilst I can ref `CoreGraphics` for both targets, because MacOS uses `NSPoint` and `NSRect` I get compiler errors.

What is the recommended way to write a shared framework that uses `CGPoint` and `NSPoint` interchangeably?  I am guessing this is possible as `CoreGraphics` can be included in MacOS or iOS projects and it will compile without error and has `NSPoint` and `CGPoint` based methods.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what the recommended way is, but here is a suggestion.

Look up the definition of `NSPoint` and you find:

```
typedef CGPoint NSPoint;
```

and similarly for `NSRect` and `NSSize`. Well that is on 10.11 at least, they may have been different *definitions* at some point but they were always the same `struct`, and structural equality holds.

So just write your library using `CG*` and have an iOS `.h` with `CG*` and an OS X `.h` with `NS*`. (Maybe write a build phase which builds the OS X `.h` from the iOS one - so the two stay in sync and correct.)

HTH